Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.lib.module.js
I get this error when running my fluent-ui blazor-server project a few times. It didn't happen for a few weeks since I started the project and now it's happening quite often although I simply changed some .razor files and I get stuck as fluent-ui's assets are not loading.
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:7246/_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.lib.module.js

I have this structure at my Program.cs (with my own services omitted):
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components;
using TestIdentityScaffoldingFluentUi.Components;
using TestIdentityScaffoldingFluentUi.Components.Account;
using TestIdentityScaffoldingFluentUi.Data;
using TestIdentityScaffoldingFluentUi.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();
builder.Services.AddDataGridEntityFrameworkAdapter();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, SendGridEmailSender>();
builder.Services.Configure<SendGridEmailSenderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ApiKey = builder.Configuration["SendGrid:ApiKey"];
    options.SenderEmail = builder.Configuration["SendGrid:SenderEmail"];
    options.SenderName = builder.Configuration["SendGrid:SenderName"];
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/404");
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.Run();


and my App.razor looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestIdentityScaffoldingFluentUi.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-UgvvN8vBkgO0luPSUl2s8TIlOSYRoGFAX4jlCIm9Adc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}


I deleted the .vs and bin folder, cleaned and rebuilt the solution. I ran the project in a different laptop by pulling it from Github and it worked there. I did the same at my pc and it works temporarily. After a few runs I get this error again.
When I browse https://localhost:7246/_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.lib.module.js, I get my own _404.razor page.

I had routing like this:
@page "/{ticker}/{name}/{accessionNumber}"

When I changed it to this, I got it working again:
@page "/companies/{ticker}/{name}/{accessionNumber}"

It seems the previous routing created issues with assets loaded from wwwroot. I'd like to know how to keep the previous routing though, but for now this will do.

that first route will match any relative URL that has three "/" and assume those are query parameters for ticker, name, and accessionNumber.  So your script src is returning a razor page.  If you really wanted to keep that first routing, you might try putting "~/" in the srcs.  That might explicitly be mapped to "wwwroot".

Use a fixed page name to begin routing:
@page "info/{ticker}/{name}/{accessionNumber}"

